# How to make sure delete query removes a row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my code:

```
$token   = $_GET['validate_activate']; // it's something like this "98j34f0j043f094f98325r"
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

// db connection here
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM activate_token WHERE token = :token");
$stmt->execute(array(':token' => $token));

if ( /* deleting is success */ ) {
    // activating the user
} else {
    // your token is invalid
}
```

Well how can I make a correct condition for that `if` statement?

Comment: or use `select count` + `fetchColumn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php);

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.

```
if ( $stmt->rowCount() ) {
    // activating the user
} else {
    // your token is invalid
}
```

Comment: hello @Drew is there a bug in newer versions? Haven't  used PHP for a couple of years

Comment: If it works on your deployment, and well tested, your method is what I would go with. It is just when you push your code around, it is dependent on the setup in action. From the manual: [not guaranteed](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the pdo statement should return True or False if the delete query was successful

```
if($stmt->execute(array($token = $_GET['validate_activate']))) {
     // activating the user
} else {
    // your token is invalid
}
```

Comment: It can be successful and not remove a row.

Comment: Assuming id is `unsigned` (0 or greater), `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = -1;` would return `true`

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt->execute` returns a bool result, true if the sql query was successful so just use the result of that in your if statement:

```
$stmtWorked = $stmt->execute(array($token));
if ($stmtWorked) {
    // activating the user
} else {
    // your token is invalid
}
```

Also you can use `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()` to count for many rows were deleted if you need to know a specific amount.